# I am just tring to create a DEFAULT RMRealm but still crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: ''NSMutableArray' is not supported as an RLMObject property. All properties must be primitives, NSString, NSDate, NSData, RLMArray, or subclasses of RLMObject.
```

Any help please. i dont know how to include it as RLMArray

```
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];
 //  NSLog(@"%@",res);

for (NSDictionary *collectionDict in [res objectForKey:@"pois"])
{
    RLMRealm *defaultREALM=[RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [defaultREALM beginWriteTransaction];
    NSMutableDictionary *mCollectionDict = [collectionDict mutableCopy];
    mCollectionDict[@"Firstname"] = collectionDict[@"name"];
    [mCollectionDict removeObjectForKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"%@===>%@",collectionDict,collectionDict[@"name"]);
    [defaultREALM commitWriteTransaction];
}
```

Comment: Are you using a NSMutableArray somewhere ? It seems to be the source of the error according to the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather in your sample, you're trying to serialize a JSON stream and then pass it to Realm. There's unfortunately an `NSArray` in there somewhere which Realm cannot accept.

Normally it would be necessary for you to manually process the contents of the dictionary to make sure every value in it is compatible with your Realm model. Luckily, there's a third party library available that can handle that for you. I definitely recommend checking out [`Realm-JSON`](https://github.com/matthewcheok/Realm-JSON) for this situation. :)

Comment: Manually, you'll need to sort through the `NSDictionary`, remove any `NSArray` objects, and manually pass their contents to a Realm `RLMArray`.

Comment: Thanks tim somehow i made my insert by checking the data model... Saw your video in youtube, it was very useful. please suggest more video links for realm.

Comment: Oh cool! Glad to hear you got it working! Haha awesome! Thanks! I'm glad you liked my video. I don't really have any recommendations for other Realm videos at the moment, but we're looking at making some new ones soon! :)